# Как создать форму для ввода пароля?

Tags: python, django

Использую базовую CBV для удаления пользователя ([`django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView`](https://django.fun/docs/django/5.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)). По умолчанию он использует пустую форму, а я хочу чтобы пользователь вводил подтверждение удаления с помощью пароля, т.е. мне нужно определить собственную форму и присвоить ее переменной класса `form_class`.
Я попробовал сделать форму, ориентируясь на [`AuthenticationForm`](https://django.fun/docs/django/5.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm):

```
class DeleteUserForm(forms.Form):
    """Форма для удаления пользователя с подтверждением при помощи пароля."""
    
    password = forms.CharField(
        label="Пароль",
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "current-password"}),
    )

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
        The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
        """
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.request.user.username
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        if username is not None and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(
                self.request, username=username, password=password
            )
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Т.е. я скопировал clear заменив `username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")` на `username = self.request.user.username`. Т.е. я добавил только поле `password` для ввода, а `username` хотел брать из `self.request`. Но, как оказалось `self.request` в таком случае - `None`. Соответственно возникает ошибка **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'.**

Сделал как в `LoginView` - переопределил `get_form_kwargs()` моей Вью:

```
class UserDeleteView(OwnerTestMixin, DeleteView):
    """Класс-представление для удаление отдельного пользователя."""

    model = User
    form_class = DeleteUserForm
    pk_url_kwarg = "user_id"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('all_users')
    template_name = "users/delete.html"
    error_message = "У вас нет прав для удаления другого пользователя."

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["request"] = self.request
        return kwargs
```

Также я скопировал методы `get_invalid_login_error()` (в которой изменил *`params={"username": self.username_field.verbose_name}`* на *`params={"username": self.request.user.username}`*) и `confirm_login_allowed()`из `AuthenticationForm`. В итоге получилось это:

```
class DeleteUserForm(forms.Form):
        """Форма для удаления пользователя с подтверждением при помощи пароля."""
    
    password = forms.CharField(
        label="Пароль",
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "current-password"}),
    )

    error_messages = {
        "invalid_login": 
            "Please enter a correct %(username)s and password. Note that both "
            "fields may be case-sensitive."
        ,
        "inactive": "This account is inactive.",
    }

    def __init__(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        The 'request' parameter is set for custom auth use by subclasses.
        The form data comes in via the standard 'data' kwarg.
        """
        self.request = request
        self.user_cache = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        username = self.request.user.username
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")

        if username is not None and password:
            self.user_cache = authenticate(
                self.request, username=username, password=password
            )
            if self.user_cache is None:
                raise self.get_invalid_login_error()
            else:
                self.confirm_login_allowed(self.user_cache)

        return self.cleaned_data
    
    def confirm_login_allowed(self, user):
        """
        Controls whether the given User may log in. This is a policy setting,
        independent of end-user authentication. This default behavior is to
        allow login by active users, and reject login by inactive users.

        If the given user cannot log in, this method should raise a
        ``ValidationError``.

        If the given user may log in, this method should return None.
        """
        if not user.is_active:
            raise ValidationError(
                self.error_messages["inactive"],
                code="inactive",
            )

    def get_invalid_login_error(self):
        return ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["invalid_login"],
            code="invalid_login",
            params={"username": self.request.user.username},
        )
```

И это вроде работает.
Но я более чем уверен, что это, мягко говоря, неправильно. Подскажите, как нужно было сделать?

Спасибо за потраченное на меня время.